# How to sum smallest five number out of seven in MS Access query rows

Tags: ms-access, vba

Example

```
history geography physics mathematics agriculture science Civics
----------------------------------------------------------------
1        2            4     5          6             7      3
```

I tried to use

```
=sum(small{1,2,3,4,5})
```

as in Excel, but what I need is the equivalent for MS Access.

Comment: Eh... Are you taking about rows or columns? You're currently representing it as columns. Also, how is this related to php?

Comment: And what to be summed, if values are (1,2,3,4,4,4,4)?

Comment: I need to sum rows, but just only five smallest numbers out of seven

Comment: if values are (1,2,3,4,4,4,4) means the sum would be of 1+2+3+4+4, what matters is just five numbers of smallest values even if the smallest numbers are equal

Comment: Access SQL queries bear user VBA functions. so you can write a **Small** function of your own.

Comment: Since you said your summing rows (?? strange thought??) you will have to create a custom aggregate function so [here you are](https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/24561564/Custom-Aggregate-Function-in-MS-Access.html)

Comment: You need to sum fields, not rows, and only the smallest 5 values of each record. This requires VBA custom function.

Comment: A UNION query could rearrange the fields into normalized structure. Another query could pull TOP 5 (sort DESC on the scores) for each student and that requires a nested subquery. But this gets even trickier because of duplicate values. Would need to calculate a record sequence ID for each student and base the TOP 5 on that field. I expect the custom function option would be faster and easier.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Top n` function to limit the result set in Access. That would be

```
SELECT Top 4 columnId
From YourTable
Order by ColumnId Asc;
```

This will return 4 rows ordered by your columnId from a-z.

Combining this with a sum function, you can caculate the total values of returned result.

i.e.

```
Select
    SUM(T2.ColumnId)
From
    (Select Top 4 ColumnId From YourTable Ordered By ColumnId) As T2;
```

This will sum the columnId value from the 4 rows.

**note**: you are taking 4 rows and adding them together, not columns.